# php file doesn't work on my Fedora Linux Apache server

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache web server on my Fedora Linux machine. Besides, I have installed PHP. I have run the following commands:

```bash
sudo dnf install httpd
sudo dnf install php php-mysqlnd php-pdo php-gd php-mbstring
sudo systemctl start httpd
sudo systemctl enable httpd
```

To check if the web server works fine, I have created a file in `/var/www/html/info.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
?>
```

the web server itself works fine, but when I open http://localhost/info.php, it treats `/var/www/html/info.php` like a downloadable file, i.e., `info.php` is downloaded to my machine instead of displaying "Hello, World!".

I've tried to modify the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file so that it contains the following lines:

```
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

    LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .phtml .html
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

However, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You should first install and **enable** httpd, verify it's running and **then** install php with

```
sudo dnf install php php-cli php-common
```

plus additional modules you may require. That should detect httpd and make the necessary changes to their configs.

Verify the installation of php by running `php -v` on the command line, then restart `httpd`.

Check if the module has been loaded and enabled by executing

```
httpd -M | grep php
```

You might also want to enable `mpm_prefork`. To find the configuration try

```
find /etc/httpd -name '*-mpm.conf'
```

and comment in the appropriate lines. Restart `httpd` one more time.

Comment: Executing `httpd -M | grep php` returns the following text `AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::2f30:b536:530f:56e4%wlp1s0. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: The module does not seem to be enabled then. Try `sudo a2enmod phpX` (where X is your PHP version, e.g. `sudo a2enmod php8`) then reload Apache. If that's not working, enable it manually.

Comment: Executing this command fails, because a2enmod is not recognized by the shell. Installing this command with `sudo dnf install a2enmod` also fails.

Comment: `If that's not working, enable it manually.`

Comment: Which module do you mean? Do I need to change `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: Yes. It has probably not been changed by the PHP installation because you've edited it before. Make sure it's the right PHP version and not inside any `IfModule`.